# Invalid scope error when authorizing apps to manage Google Cloud Storage

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

We are working on Google Cloud Storage using Json API and while authorizing the web app to manage the storage, we encounter the following error before the consent page. And the strange thing is that, we have no issue with our previously developed services that utilize other Google API(eg. DCM, Adwords, Youtube etc).

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

This app hasn’t been verified to access: {invalid = [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly]} Please contact the developer for assistance. Are you the developer? If this project needs these scopes, sign in to an account with access to edit your project and try again. If not, contact the developer for help.
```

We've looked around the web and many of them including some posts in stackoverflow point us to the manual review process by Google. I have tested joining the risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps) it does resolve the issue. With this, can I confirm if this is the real cause or it's some other reason?